# Why doesn't this code populate my GridView images/How do I populate nested images to GridView?

Tags: c#, user-interface, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to populate a GridView with images in my C# code.
The GridView has a data template containing a Grid, with an Image inside of it.

When I try to run code similar to this on a standalone Image object, it works just fine, but when I try to run this to populate images in the GridView, the Grid objects are populated, but not the Images within them.

If I force a condition that causes the catch loop to execute, the same thing happens (grid displays, but no image inside of it).

**Edit**: After some more experimentation I noticed the image source is not the only property being ignored. If I change the Grid name or background, or the image Name when generating the object, none of these changes apply - it is always using information from the control's DataTemplate and not using information from the item I have added.

Here is the code-behind.

```
public async void AddImage(WorkingImage img)
    {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image i = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image();
        try
        {
            FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await img.file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            await bmp.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            i.Source = bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed to add image source" + ex.Message);
            i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Resources/FailedImageRender.png"));
        }
        Grid g = new Grid();
            g.Children.Add(i);

        gridView.Items.Add(g);
    }
```

Here is the XAML for the custom control.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MyProjectName.Classes.Controls.IUAreaExpander"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:ViperContentManager.Classes.Controls"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OverlayColor">#FFD0D0D0</SolidColorBrush>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Control.Resources>

<controls:Expander
    x:Name="expander"
    ExpandDirection="Down"
    IsExpanded="True">

    <controls:AdaptiveGridView
        x:Name="gridView"
        DesiredWidth="140"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemHeight="140"
        SelectionMode="Extended"
        StretchContentForSingleRow="False">
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="Image">
                <Grid
                    Width="NaN"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource OverlayColor}"
                    BorderThickness="5,5,5,5">
                    <Image
                        x:Name="EquipImage"
                        Opacity="1"
                        Stretch="UniformToFill">
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0.5" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OverlayColor}" />
            </Style>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
</controls:Expander>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have noticed that the image source is not the only property being
> ignored.

Yes, you are right.
The image cannot be added correctly because the image in the `AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate` cannot get the source. You can create a new class and direct the source of the image to the image list you bind in `ItemsSource`, so that you can achieve the behavior you want by adding or deleting images in the `ObservableCollection`.

```
       <controls:AdaptiveGridView
    x:Name="gridView"
    DesiredWidth="140"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemHeight="140"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind imageList}"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    StretchContentForSingleRow="False">
            <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:WorkingImage">
                    <Grid
                Width="NaN"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource OverlayColor}"
                BorderThickness="5,5,5,5">
                        <Image
                    Source="{Binding bitmapSource}"
                    x:Name="EquipImage"
                    Opacity="1"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill">
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0.5" />
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OverlayColor}" />
                </Style>
            </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

Because the code you provided is limited, this is my quick test code, the specific use needs to be changed according to your `WorkingImage` class.

---

```
public class WorkingImage
{
    public string FileSource { get; set; }
    public BitmapSource bitmapSource { get; set; }
}


public sealed partial class IUAreaExpander : UserControl
{

    ObservableCollection<WorkingImage> imageList = new ObservableCollection<WorkingImage>();

    public IUAreaExpander()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();         

        imageList.Add(
            new WorkingImage()
            {
                bitmapSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"))
            }
         );

        imageList.Add(
            new WorkingImage()
            {
                bitmapSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"))
            }
         );          
    }

    public  void AddImage()
    {
        imageList.Add(
            new WorkingImage()
            {
                bitmapSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"))
            }
         );
      
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Junjie, thanks for the answer! After I posted this question I did suspect I needed to do something with ItemsSource and use x:Bind butI still wasn't 100% there - using bitmapSource and the Observable collection was what I needed, thanks!